# Avoid multiple HttpRequest for inserting CheckBoxList selected data

Tags: c#, wcf

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < chkBusinessLocationDetails.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (chkBusinessLocationDetails.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    long RowId = myvalue
                    string json1 = "{'CommonCategory':" + chk.Items[i].Value + ",'CommonCategoryRowId':" + RowId + "}";
                    status.Text = Classforhttprequest.HttpPost("http://localhost/MyService/MetaData.svc/CommonCategoryAttributesID", json1);

                }

            }  


}
```

Here In order to insert Selected Chkbox list data in to DB I need to call the service for many times that equals to  the number of items selected in checkbox list....can i acheive my requirement by calling one time and insert selected values

Comment: Cant you simply create a list of key-value pairs in the for loop, and move the HttpPost call after the loop?

Comment: will you please implement the code how it will be..........

Comment: Is it [August 10th](http://nationaldaycalendar.com/days-2/national-lazy-day-august-10/) already?

Comment: as I am not getting your point i request u to suggest..... I tried something like this

Answer (score 0):

from then ..... need to create a function in DB

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Splitter](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @table TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(8000)       

select @idx = 1       
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

while @idx!= 0       
begin       
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
    if @idx!=0       
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
    else       
        set @slice = @String       

    if(len(@slice)>0)  
        insert into @table(Items) values(@slice)       

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
    if len(@String) = 0 break       
end   
return  end;
```

then in Insert SP need to do like this.......

```
INSERT INTO CommonCategoryAttributes
   (CommonCategoryRowId,CommonCategoryAttributeName,Priority)
   SELECT @CommonCategoryRowId, @CommonCategoryAttributeName, @Priority
   FROM dbo.[Split] (@CommonCategoryAttributeName, ',')
```

it works for exec CommonCategoryAttributesID 1, 'Gopal,Reddy',2 ;